Generate JPEG-in-TIFF without recompressing JPEG source in Java
I need to wrap a JPEG image as TIFF (aka. "JPEG-in-TIFF") without changing the JPEG data (i.e. without decompressing and re-compressing the original JPEG image, which would hurt the image quality by introducing artifacts).
How can I do this with Java?
The process need not do everything "automagically" (there is at least some information that would need to be supplied in order for the necessary TIFF tags to be generated correctly), but the resulting (single-page) TIFF should be well-formed and valid.

@user3344003, we have a code of conduct here. Please don't call people names.

My library, TwelveMonkeys ImageIO contains some low-level TIFF classes (like TIFFWriter) that can help you create the TIFF structure around your JPEG. The JPEG data can then be copied mostly as-is into the new file (perhaps skipping a few non-essential segments from the JPEG stream, to produce a valid TIFF, but most readers will cope anyway...).

To elaborate, you need to read up on the TIFF spec to find what tags are required for JPEG (compression type 7), and then extract width/height, bits per pixel and other essential meta data from jeg JPEG, copy that into an IFD and write it using the TIFFWriter. The class can also compute the size of the IFD, which will help you compute the offset to the JPEG data stream.

@HaraldK I have some knowledge of what you mention (TIFF format). I know of your contributions (big thanks!). I will experiment with TIFFWriter, but I find it a bit under-documented, unless I'm missing on some online content (e.g. what is the proper order of calls to generate a TIFF?).
Thanks, again!

Perhaps I spoke too soon. I'll be looking on how TIFFImageWriter works, which uses TIFFWriter. Any other suggestions?

@Doc It could probably have had better documentation... But yes, look at the TIFFImageWriter, that is what I would suggest. Or perhaps the TIFFUtiltities  class, which might be a litte closer to what you need to do.
Let me know if you have trouble figuring it out!
